# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve $$_gendir\app\item-receive-return.module.ngfactory.ts'

Tags: node.js, angular

```
ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir async
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
'E:\saif_pos_sys\pos\src\$$_gendir\app\pages\item-receive-return\item-
receive-return.module.ngfactory.ts' in 'E:\saif_pos_sys\pos\src\$$_gendir'
@ ./src/$$_gendir async
@ ./~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
@ ./src/app/app.component.ts
@ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts
@ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi ./src/main.ts
```

After aot build `npm run build:prod:aot` this error occured. I have tried to change the version to angular/cli@1.2.4, zone.js@0.8.14 and install
enhanced-resolve@3.3.0 but still it shows this error. Every time I deleted the node_modules, npm cache clear and then again npm install. Do not know what is the main problem? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Looks like that error is limited to AOT building, if you don't want to build it with --aot=false you should double check your solution with this aot checklist. https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter#aot--donts

Comment: @IsuruFonseka I am using angular-cli@1.2.4 and angular@4.1.3, so does this version for angular is compatible ??

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem of this error.I had written the module file name with a capital letter such as `Item-receive-return-module.ts` but in the page.routing.ts the module name was in small letter. After I changed it to `item-receive-return-module.ts` finally the problem is solved.